# Get-WSManInstance ignores -ErrorAction parameter

Tags: powershell, error-handling

Consider the following script:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

$selectorset = @{
    Transport = "HTTPS"
    Address = "*"
}

$listener = Get-WSManInstance -ErrorAction Stop `
    -ResourceURI 'winrm/config/Listener' -SelectorSet $selectorset

write "Bye!"
```

For the case when the HTTPS listener is absent, the `Get-WSManInstance` invocation throws a "cannot find the resource" error (and this is expected). However, this invocation seems to only respect the value of `$ErrorActionPreference` and completely ignore the value of the `-ErrorAction` parameter (which is supposed to override the value of `$ErrorActionPreference`), you may try different combinations of the supported values for these two settings. I have tested the behavior with PowerShell versions `5.1.17763.1490` and `4.0`.

If I get it right, the error in this case *is* a "non-terminating error", otherwise `$ErrorActionPreference` would have been ignored too.

In contrast, when I test the `-ErrorAction` parameter with some standard cmdlets like `Write-Error` or `Get-Item`, it seems to work as expected.

I am quite new to PowerShell and trying to understand if I am missing something here or it is a bug with `Get-WSManInstance` (or maybe there are some implementation specifics to this particular cmdlet).

Comment: Use `-ErrorAction Stop` for expressions inside a `try{..} catch{..}` block. This will make the code enter the catch on exceptions.

Comment: @theo, thanks, in my real script I indeed have resorted to using `try{..} catch{..}` prior to posting this question, but with `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"`, as the `-ErrorAction` parameter is ignored for this cmdlet - hence the question.